# Relationship in conceptual model (ER diagram)

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I have a simple and probably. banal question. I am working on the first, conceptual phase of an entity-relationship diagram.

This DABMS will be used by some Managers, that will control (registrate and modify accounts) of customers.

In my diagram I have the two entities "MANAGER" and "CUSTOMER". Is it necessary to connect them with a relationship (M:N), to specify that the Managers are those who will manage the customers' account, or this relationship is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

> to specify that the Managers are those who will manage the customers

No. ER diagrams typically show relations that are reflected in your database.

Example, what would be visible in your ERD

- Each customer has a manager assigned who's responsible for this customer => 1:n - each customer has one manager but one manager can be responsible for multible customers.

Comment: Thank you! So do you think that this information would be useless in the database? (knowing which manager is responsible for each customer's account)

Comment: It's a common requirement to have a "responsible manager" assigned to each customer and I didn't say this feature is useless. But if you don't have such a feature, then managers and customers are not related in your db and then you would not add a relationship in your ERD. - There's no relationship just because in the UI, managers will do something with customers.

Comment: Yes, these managers are just those who have to create the customers' accounts on the website and eventually delete these accounts if the customers leave